# How to use multiple Datasouces (Dataflow & On-Prem) in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dataset, dataflow, powerbi-datasource

Hi I currently have a challenge I need some expert advise with. I have a Power BI report the uses a dataflow and an SQL connection. The issue i'm facing is that the dataflow is set to refresh from cloud sources ever 2 mins (using power automate), and the SQL Data would need to be refreshed once daily (using enterprise gateway). The problem is that my automation refreshes the dataset every 2 mins so the SQL connection is getting refreshed as well, and that take about 7-10 mins so the updates keep getting delayed.

What would be the be the best way to have both done independently?

Comment: Did you try directquery for Dataflow?

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/power-bi-dataflows-direct-query-support/

you can refresh dataflow independent (every 2 min), but dataset may be refreshed once a day

Comment: @msta42a I enabled the option in the documentation and followed all the steps but only getting the option to import just the same.

Comment: I finally got it to work for 6 of 7 of the tables *face palm...all the tables are coming from Smartsheet. I noticed the icon beside the 7th table is shown differently (not as a view) but it has no transform steps that the others that already work done have